# How should I get data from a process spawned from a reducer for a different component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to structure actions and reducers in React/Redux.

What I have is essentially an output component (`LogOutput`) and a button (`RunScript`). When the user clicks the button, the result should be displayed in the output.

What I *thought* I was supposed to do was write an action for the button:

**actions/RunScript.js**

```
export const EXEC = 'EXEC';

export function exec() {
  return {
    type: EXEC
  };
}
```

and then put the logic in the reducer:

**reducers/RunScript.js**

```
export default function execScript(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case EXEC_PLUGIN:
      // Create a child process
      tail = child.spawn('tail', ['/var/log/system.log']);
      tail.stdout.on('data', data => {
         console.log(data.toString());
      });
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

this works, however I do not understand how I should pipe the spawned process data to the `LogOutput` component.

Comment: You might be interested in looking at [middleware](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html)

Comment: You may want to look into [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) for async stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close the loop on this, here's what I ended up going with:

**middleware/RunScript.js**

```
function createStreamOutputMiddleware() {
  return (store) => (next) => (action) => {
    let proc = {};

    switch (action.type) {
      case EXEC_PLUGIN:
        proc = child.spawn('tail', ['/var/log/system.log']);
        proc.stdout.on('data', data => {
          console.log(data.toString());
        })
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }

    return next(action);
  };
}
const streamOutput = createStreamOutputMiddleware();

export default streamOutput;
```